# Spring bind issue

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Wondering what's the best way to handle this scenario:

I have a Spring bound (via Spring binding) form with first item of the list:

```
myList[0].customerFName
myList[0].customerMName
myList[0].customerLName
myList[0].customerSSN
```

There's a scenario, in code, where user can delete this record making the list empty.
Now when the page comes back with the list empty, it throws an exception for all the bound fields.
What is the way to handle this scenario?
Should I just add an empty object to this list so that page appears back with empty fields?

Comment: Consider adding some code.  Maybe show how you are binding to "myList[0]".  I suspect you are using annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either don't reference using the index just iterate over items, or make it an autopopulating list.